# How do I combine lists with multiple values into main lists for users to select from?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, user-input

```
import random

#lists to describe what trucks people like
person= ['I', 'she', 'he']
emtotion=['loves', 'hates', 'likes']
Trucks= ['chevys', 'fords', 'rams']`

#lists to describe an animals favorite foods
animal= ['dogs', 'cats', 'birds']
emotion_2=['love', 'hates']
food= ['tuna', 'meat', 'seeds', 'garbage']
```

for the lists above, how do i group the TWO seperate lists of three lists into 2 seperate master type lists? example:

```
# a main call to describe peoples emotions towards trucks
truck_preference =     
person= ['I', 'she', 'he']
emtotion=['loves', 'hates', 'likes']
Trucks= ['chevys', 'fords', 'rams']

#a main call for all lists describing an animals foods
animal_foods=
animal= ['dogs', 'cats', 'birds']
emotion_2=['love', 'hates']
food= ['tuna', 'meat', 'seeds', 'garbage']
```

so for example, once i have my TWO main categories, I can ask a user for input to select "animal_foods" or "truck_preference" and randomly display the values to form a string of text, a simple 3 word random text. then ask the user to select a list again, this time "animal_foods" and display the same randomness again.

this is what I have now, to print the random items.

```
    count = 0
while count < 10:   
        print(random.choice(Person), end= " ")
        print(random.choice(Emotion), end= " ")
        print(random.choice(Trucks), end= " " )
        print('\n')
        count = count +1

 count = 0
    while count < 10:   
            print(random.choice(animal), end= " ")
            print(random.choice(Emotion_2), end= " ")
            print(random.choice(Food), end= " " )
            print('\n')
            count = count +1
```

But, my biggest problem is how to ask a user to select either the "Truck_preference" to print the items randomly to form the random texts and and then ask the user to select the "animal_foods" list values to form random text about that.

so what Id hope to accomplish summed up is:

```
import random

truck_preference = [3 key lists and their values]
animal_foods =[3 key lists and their values]

input("which scenario would you like to run")
#user inputs Truck_preference
 output: I love chevys
         he likes fords
        she hates rams
        he loves rams
        i like fords
        ....etc

input("which scenario would you like to run")
#user inputs animal_foods
 output:  Cats hate seeds
          dogs love meat
          dogs hate meat
         birds hate tuna
         cats love tuna
         birds love seeds
        dogs love garbage
         ...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a flexible mechanism that makes it much more straightforward to extend if you either wanted to add more words to each bin or add/reorder more words to a specific sentence, or even new word/sentence classes altogether.

```
import random

d_1 = {
        0: ['I', 'He', 'She'],
        1: ['loves', 'hates', 'likes'],
        2: ['Chevys', 'Fords', 'Rams']
}

d_2 = {
        0: ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Birds'],
        1: ['love', 'hate'],
        2: ['tuna', 'meat', 'seeds', 'garbage']
}

def generate_sentence(choice_of_dict):
    return ' '.join(random.choice(choice_of_dict[i]) for i in range(len(choice_of_dict)))

generate_sentence(d_1)
>> 'She hates Chevys'
generate_sentence(d_2)
>> 'Dogs hate tuna'
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing which might help you here is to use nested lists to describe these sentences, and then have a function which generates a random sentence given such a nested list; here is one way this might be done.

```
truck_preferences = [['I', 'she', 'he'], ['loves', 'hates', 'likes'], ['chevys', 'fords', 'rams']]
animal_foods=['dogs', 'cats', 'birds'], ['love', 'hates'], ['tuna', 'meat', 'seeds', 'garbage']

def random_sentence(nested_list):
    words=[random.choice(sublist) for sublist in nested_list]
    return " ".join(words)
```